# MissingMethodException when I try to call a collaborator method

Tags: groovy

Setting the time to a date where the time is passed in the format `hh:mm` for example `8:00`, the following code works as expected:

```
package demo

import static java.util.Calendar.*

class Helper {

    public static final Date setTimeToDate(final Date date, final String time) {
        Calendar calendar = date.toCalendar()
        Integer hourOfDay = time.tokenize(':')[0].toInteger()

        calendar.set hourOfDay: hourOfDay, minute: 0, second: 0

        calendar.getTime()
    }
}
```

Now I try to extract the logic of getting the hour of day to its own method, so I adapt the code to this requirement as follows:

```
package demo

import static java.util.Calendar.*

class Helper {

    public static final Date setTimeToDate(final Date date, final String time) {
        Calendar calendar = date.toCalendar()
        Integer hourOfDay = getHour(time)

        calendar.set hourOfDay: hourOfDay, minute: 0, second: 0

        calendar.getTime()
    }

    private Integer getHour(final String time) {
        time.tokenize(':')[0].toInteger()
    }
}
```

When I try to call the setTimeToDate method

```
println Helper.setTimeToDate(new Date(), '8:00')
```

I get the following error

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static demo.Helper.getHour() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [8:00]
Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String)
    at demo.Helper.setTimeToDate(Script1.groovy:9)
    at demo.Helper$setTimeToDate.call(Unknown Source)
    at demo.Script1.run(Script1.groovy:21)
```

I especially do not understand this part of the error message `[8:00]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeToDate` is static but `getHour` is not, so it cannot be called without an instance. Make `getHour` static too and it will be callable.